# How Can I make UTFGrid files?

Tags: web-mapping, utfgrid

I have been looking at the [UTFGrid](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec) specification and the usage of UTFGrid in [Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/utfgrid.html).

How do I create the required UTFGrid files for my data in PostGIS?

Answer (score 3):

[This blog post is about exactly that](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2012/02/24/utfgrids-with-openlayers-and-tilestache/). Looks like TileStache will handle it for you.

Comment: The only problem with this is that TileStache supports only EPSG 4326 & EPSG 3857 for the projection. I was looking for a more generic projection (UTM projection)

Answer (score 1):

You can render UTF8 grids in mapnik directly - use [the mapnik grid renderer](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/MapnikRenderers#grid_renderer), which nicely addresses the issue of being able to produce an image in any dimension.

For example in python:

```py
import mapnik
import json

m = mapnik.load_map("map.xml")
layer_index = 0 #First layer on the map - index in m.layers
key = "__id__"  #Field used for the key in mapnik (should probably be unique)
resolution = 4  #Pixel resolution of output.
                #I'm pretty sure valid valuse are 1,2 and 4, but don't quote me
fields = []     #Attributes to output against the key

d = mapnik.render_grid(m, layer_index, key, resolution, fields) #returns a dictionary
json.dump(d, open("utf8.dump", "wb"), indent=2)
```

If you need help building your `map.xml` file for mapnik I'd go for [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) - a really fantastic program for building mapnik xml from [Carto CSS](http://mapbox.com/carto/api/2.1.0/).

Comment: Bonus: in TileMill it's dead easy to bring in PostGIS data with a native connector as well.